# Avoid the SnackBar going full-width when the window is too small

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, snackbar

The SnackBar stretches from one end of the screen to the other when the window is not wide enough, is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found an answer: set a maxWidth to the SnackBar and set the margin you want between it and the borders of the screen, this way the SnackBar won't neither stretch nor dock to the bottom when the windows gets smaller.